# What is the SRID for this .prj file?

Tags: qgis, postgis, coordinate-system, srid

```
PROJCS["3900_SC_Nad_83",GEOGCS
        ["GCS_North_American_1983",DATUM
            ["D_North_American_1983",SPHEROID ["GRS_1980",6378137,298.257222101]],
                PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.0],UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]
            ],
                    PROJECTION["Lambert_Conformal_Conic"],
                        PARAMETER["False_Easting",1999996.000],
                        PARAMETER["False_Northing",0.000],
                        PARAMETER["Central_Meridian",-81.00000000],
                        PARAMETER["Standard_Parallel_1",32.50000000],
                        PARAMETER["Standard_Parallel_2",34.83333333],
                        PARAMETER["Latitude_Of_Origin",31.83333333],
                        UNIT["FOOT_US",0.3048006096]
        ]
```

I got this .prj file from a local county government in SC to update their parcel information and I am trying to import the shapefile into PostgreSQL and be sure that I have the correct SRID. This file indicates that it uses US feet, and I want to be sure that I am using the correct SRID does anyone know what the correct SRID is? 102733 which is in SC State Plane is supposed to be using the International Ft and not US Ft.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and outline where you got the file, what your research has told you, and include any extra information you can that you already know about the data

Answer (score 5, accepted):

NAD 1983 StatePlane South Carolina FIPS 3900 Feet

102733

http://spatialreference.org/ref/esri/102733/

Comment: Yeah, this is right.  I missed the 3900 part and the differences in the false easting value

Comment: but 102733 uses an international ft and not US ft, right?

Comment: @Matt why do you think international ft? It is defined for the US only.

Comment: 2273 says intl feet, 102733 just says feet

Comment: SC uses the intl ft for it's state plane.

Comment: @Matt the `prj` in your question says `FOOT_US`

Comment: @Midavalo yes, my point exactly, that is why I'm confused because I knew that SC State Plane was in international feet (even though it doesn't say that in the SRID) and this .prj file is in US feet.

Comment: quick note though, 102733 did work.

Comment: @Matt please add this to your question, as this sounds like it might be your actual question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54142/discussion-between-matt-and-midavalo).

Comment: The difference between us_ft and int_ft is about 0,0002%, so it might be considered equal.

Comment: Please note that 102733 is an Esri wkid, not an EPSG one.

Answer (score 2):

My (Esri) PCS documentation lists the following:

> NAD_1983_StatePlane_South_Carolina_ FIPS_3900 **32133** USA - South
>   Carolina
>   NAD_1983_StatePlane_South_Carolina_ FIPS_3900_Feet **102733** USA - South Carolina
>   NAD_1983_StatePlane_South_Carolina_ FIPS_3900_Feet_Intl **2273** USA - South Carolina

Note that 2273 mentions International feet and 102733 just mentions feet.